# Is there a good guide to using "The DJB Way" with FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd

I'm rapidly becoming a FreeBSD convert (from Linux). I'm also intrigued by `djb`'s software. Is there a good guide to replacing the standard set of FreeBSD utilities with their `djb` equivalent? It would be swell if that also happened to leverage `port`s, but I'm willing to do it manually if that's the way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

djb as in [Daniel J. Bernstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_J._Bernstein)?  He has a limited set of software that he has written, you are not going to replace many FreeBSD "utilities" with his software.  I am not confident that you understand what you're asking.

I use his software regularly and greatly appreciate his approach to secure software development.  However, his lack of consideration of standard UNIX conventions such as the [Filesystem Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) can be frustrating.  Last I heard, Theo removed djb's software from OpenBSD ports due to his licensing and conflict over the filesystem hierarchy.

You could replace your MTA with [QMAIL](http://www.qmail.org/).

You could replace your DNS with [djbdns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djbdns).

You could run a static content Web server with [Publicfile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publicfile).

You could run a combination of tcpserver and daemontools instead of a more common [superserver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-server) like *inetd.  daemontools is very useful to keep software running in case of crashing, but you have to run in the foreground.

Comment: If I could give an extra +1 for "I am not confident that you understand what you're asking.", I would.

Comment: I'm aware that there's not a "djbnix". I specifically meant replacing Sendmail w/ qmail and BIND with djbdns, as well possibly using clockspeed, etc. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I was mostly concerned with how to replace important chunks of the system like the MTA, as well as any problems that might arise from things like the difference in expected filesystem layouts you mention.

Comment: I run QMAIL standard across the board.  It's my preferred MTA.  If you're not transitioning an existing infrastructure, it should be seamless.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Warner's Answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/160812/is-there-a-good-guide-to-using-the-djb-way-with-freebsd/160817#160817), there are ports for:

```
QMail: /usr/ports/mail/qmail
DJBdns: /usr/ports/dns/djbdns
Publicfile: /usr/ports/www/publicfile
```

As a side note I'm not a fan of these software packages. I am a fan of the more popular packages:

```
Sendmail - Built in
Postfix: /usr/ports/mail/postfix
Courier: /usr/ports/mail/courier (less popular, but my preferred)
BIND - Built in
Apache: /usr/ports/www/apache22
```

In any case, there's several FreeBSD users around this site, so feel free to ask if you have any questions!